# SchemaGen wrongly generates unnecessary association tables

Tags: hibernate, schemagen

I have a very simple DB schema, the classic **Order ---(one to many)---> OrderItem <---(many to one)--- Product**

However when I use SchemaGen to generate the DDL it creates an extra layer **orders_orders_item, and product_orders_item**, in effect adding a redundant layer of association tables :

```
create table orders (order_id bigint not null auto_increment, order_amout varchar(255), primary key (order_id)) engine=InnoDB;
create table orders_item (orders_item_id bigint not null auto_increment, order_amount integer, product_id bigint not null, primary key (orders_item_id)) engine=InnoDB;
create table orders_orders_item (OrderEntity_order_id bigint not null, orderItems_orders_item_id bigint not null) engine=InnoDB;
create table product (id bigint not null auto_increment, name varchar(255), price decimal(19,2), primary key (id)) engine=InnoDB;
create table product_orders_item (ProductEntity_id bigint not null, orders_orders_item_id bigint not null) engine=InnoDB;
```

It seems to think there is a *many to many* association between **orders** and **orders_item**, and between **product** and **orders_item**.

Why is this happening?

My entity classes look like this :

Orders :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "orders")
public class OrderEntity {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "order_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @OneToMany
    private List<OrderItemEntity> orderItems;

    protected OrderEntity() {
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public List<OrderItemEntity> getOrderItems() {
        return orderItems;
    }
    public void setOrderItems(List<OrderItemEntity> orderItems) {
        this.orderItems = orderItems;
    }
}
```

Orders Item :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "orders_item")
public class OrderItemEntity {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "orders_item_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "product_id", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private ProductEntity product = new ProductEntity();

    @Column(name = "order_amount")
    private int amount;

    protected OrderItemEntity() {
    }

    public OrderItemEntity(ProductEntity product, int amount) {
        super();
        this.product = product;
        this.amount = amount;
    }
    public int getAmount() {
        return amount;
    }
    public void setAmount(int amount) {
        this.amount = amount;
    }
    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public ProductEntity getProduct() {
        return product;
    }
    public void setProduct(ProductEntity product) {
        this.product = product;
    }
}
```

Product :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "product")
public class ProductEntity {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @OneToMany
    private List<OrderItemEntity> orders = new ArrayList<>();

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "price")
    private BigDecimal price;

    protected ProductEntity() {
    }

    public ProductEntity(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public ProductEntity(String name, BigDecimal price) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.price = price;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public BigDecimal getPrice() {
        return price;
    }
    public void setPrice(BigDecimal price) {
        this.price = price;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `orders_orders_item` table :

Since you haven't specified `@JoinColumn`, instead of only one foreign key, an extra table with two foreign keys is created.

```
orders_orders_item (OrderEntity_order_id, orderItems_orders_item_id)
```

To solve this you should add `@JoinColumn` annotation to `OrderEntity`.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "orders")
public class OrderEntity {

    //...

    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name = "order_id")
    private List<OrderItemEntity> orderItems;
}
```

With this mapping only an `order_id` column will be added to the `orders_item` table. `orders_orders_item` table will not be created unnecessarily

- `product_orders_item` table:

There is a bidirectional relationship between `orders_item` and `product`. You specified `@JoinColumn` on the `orders_item` side. This led to the creation of `product_id` column on the `orders_item` table which is right.

But on the other side, since you haven't specified `mappedBy` and it is a bidirectional relationship DB tries to make the link by creating the `product_orders_item` table.

You should add `mappedBy` attribute to `orders` field.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "product")
public class ProductEntity {

    // ...

    @OneToMany (mappedBy="product")
    private List<OrderItemEntity> orders = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

This tells that the bidirectional relation is already created between `product` and `orders_item` (no need to map `orders` field). There is no need an extra table creation, etc. Thanks to the `@JoinColumn`, `product_id` column is created in the `orders_item` table.

Answer (score 1):

Your associations:

```
@Entity
public class OrderEntity {

    @OneToMany
    private List<OrderItemEntity> orderItems;

    // ...
}

@Entity
public class ProductEntity {

    @OneToMany
    private List<OrderItemEntity> orders = new ArrayList<>();

    // ...
}
```

are [unidirectional](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations-one-to-many-unidirectional) `@OneToMany`. So, as it's stated in the documentation:

> When using a unidirectional `@OneToMany` association, Hibernate resorts to using a link table between the two joining entities.

You can correct it by adding `@JoinColumn` annotation as it is mentioned in the @Hülya answer. (It was added in [JPA 2.0](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/What_is_new_in_JPA_2.0%3F)). But [bidirectional](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations-one-to-many-bidirectional) `@OneToMany` is much more efficient when managing the collection persistence state. Every element removal only requires a single update (in which the foreign key column is set to `NULL`).